Trying to match any set of elements with a regex that have &nbsp; or whitespace
So I am currently using this regex, but I see a flaw in it for p and div tags:
(<(p?|div?)>).+(\s|&nbsp;)+(<\/(p?|div?)>)+
Given the current string:
<div class="blahblahblah testing"><ul><li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li></ul></div><div>     </div><p>&nbsp;</p><div class="blahblah">&nbsp;</div><div class="test2"><p class="blah"> &nbsp; </p><p>&nbsp;</p></div><div class="blahblah">&nbsp;</div><p> </p><div class="blahblah">Testing</div><div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
As you can see in the pic attached, it is matching the string with <div class="blahblah">Testing</div> and I would like it to only match whitespace or empty or &nbsp; inside of a p or div tag.  How can I achieve this?

(<(p?|div?)>).+(\s|&nbsp;)+(<\/(p?|div?)>)+
I am trying to match empty p and/or div tags or that have &nbsp; inside of them.  I need to match <p> to the next closing </p> and <div> tag to the next closing </div>

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Use a HTML/DOM parser to parse HTML. Regex isn't a HTML parser.

Hello, so I have followed examples of using PHP DomDocument and examples are not working in PHP 8.2+, example here:  https://onlinephp.io/c/42698

Thanks, I think I found a solution for now:  <(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>+(?:&nbsp;|\s)+[^'">]+> seems to work.

The sample PHP code you provided at the online sandbox does not seem to match your question here at all. The sample also includes turning off errors, which is usually not a good thing when trying to debug/test something new.

Do you mean to match any outer div/p with nested div/p inside that only contain space or &nbsp;? See if this regex (demo) helps. It's adjusted pattern from an old answer (recursive regex). To use it in PHP best take the escaped pattern from regex101' code generator.

Thanks, that actually is a nice working example.  Very much appreciated!

@SolomonClossonC Glad that helped! I made a little flaw, here is the better working pattern or without processing html-comments, further without explanation the pattern in one line/no free-spacing mode: <((p|div)[^"'>]*+(?:"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*+"[^"'>]*|'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*+'[^"'>]*)*+>\s*(?:&nbsp;\s*)*(?:<(?1)\s*(?:&nbsp;\s*)*)*+</\2>)

@SolomonClossonC If my closure is inappropriate, let me know! It sounded that  Casimir's answer adjusted a bit was helpful. I would not write a fresh one.
